# Heroku Connect - Able to Handle Recursive Model Fields like Django?

Tags: python, heroku, heroku-connect

In Django (and other frameworks), I can do the following:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    prerequisites = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False)
```

This forces Django to produce a multi-select (picklist) field  in the admin, where I can select multiple instances of this same model. [Shown Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical)

I want to be able to do this recursive strategy in Salesforce. My worry is that if I create this model setup in Django, it won't translate properly to Salesforce via Heroku Connect. Is there a way to set this up in Salesforce so it behaves like the above code?